# Witadmin importprocessconfig path access denied

Tags: process, path, tfs-2015

I am trying to import a process config to an existing project via commandline power-tools, but everytime I try importing I get an access denied error, but i surely have access to the path.

Does anyone know, what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't download all of Process Template in one go.

Although you are looking to achieve this through WITAdmin utility, however, 
you can also download them by using the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i already know that.
the only problem with this solution is, that my company wants me to write a script with which they can change the process template of all projects in a collection at once and thats why i am asking if there is a possibility to upload the whole process template to a project.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things we need to check here.

1. Run your Application as "Run as Administrator" and see if this resolves this issue.
2. Check if you belong to TFS Administrator Group to ensure that you have valid permissions.

I am currently running WITAdmin utility from the following location (VS 2015 + TFS 2015 Power Tools) and never came across any issue.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\witadmin.exe

Additionally, you can post some code to understand how you are doing it.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, but I think the problem might be, that I am importing workitems from a svn repository, where I don't have enough rights.

Is there a command to import the whole process template all in one?